# Partial data displayed and rest by tooltip using JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, model, tooltip, jtextpane

I just wanted a code where I can display partial text and the remaining text by the tool tip using 'JTextPane'.

Eg: If text is 'Java is re useable'. I want it to display 'Java is ...'
Then I want to add a tooltip to display the rest of the data.

Please do let me know how it is done.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this question is already asked. See if it answers your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915869/how-can-i-create-an-autocomplete-popup-in-a-jtextpane-in-java

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please tell us what you have tried to achieve your goal.

Comment: Or maybe have a look at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561506/adding-tooltips-to-jtextpane

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which demonstrates what you are trying to achieve and the problems you have encountered.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of a `JLabel` whose current width is less that its preferred size. You can study the effect by resizing the enclosing frame in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597688/230513), which overrides `layoutCL()` to display the text layout state.

[image]